# Importing sharp edges from 3ds Max

Tags: import

Is there a addon for importing sharp edges from 3ds to blender?
Edit:
I tried exporting collada file from 3ds to blender, but it didn't work

Comment: Hello and welcome. This looks more like a request than a question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, and yes. Blender and 3DS Max cannot open each other’s basic format, but both can export and import multiple other formats, such as Collada. Such formats usually include things like split normals (A.K.A. sharp edges). Use such formats to bridge between the two softwares.